# System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: multithreading, internet-explorer, testing, watin, shdocvw

Automation using WatiN is being carried out. Using couple of simultaneous threads to test the application. Few threads are failed and log report/stack trace says the following.

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2.get_HWND()
   at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEBrowser.get_hWnd()
   at WatiN.Core.Browser.get_hWnd()
   at WatiN.Core.DomContainer.StartDialogWatcher()
   at WatiN.Core.IE.CreateNewIEAndGoToUri(Uri uri, IDialogHandler logonDialogHandler, Boolean createInNewProcess)
   at WatiN.Core.IE..ctor(Boolean createInNewProcess)
   at Core.BaseWatinTestWrapper.Run()
```

Following this exception there is another exception being raised i.e.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005.
```

Please provide some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We're getting this error as well since we switched to 64bit computers. Our tests already run in the correct apartment state.

Comment: Window handles are difficult in COM interop, they are 64-bit values on a 64-bit operating system.  Change the main project's Platform target to x86.

Answer (score 2):

I was also using couple of threads and was getting the same error. Make your main method [MTAThread]. This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, WatiN explicitly is single-threaded [STApartment]
- http://watin.org/documentation/sta-apartmentstate/
If you wish to have such test, I believe you need separate processes in OS-level.
I can't tell for sure does you approach collide with this requirement, yet I'd suggest single instance for single browser (and it's descendent windows / processess).

Also, there might be another hickup - WatiN connects to IE using browser's internals, but if there's any Windows / User Session related activity along the way, this might bring additional confusion.