# WatiN fails to find any browser on a x64 system

Tags: c#, interop, 64-bit, pinvoke, watin

I am seeing some weird issues on a x64 system running our .NET app.

Our app uses WatiN to perform automated actions on browser based web apps.

On the said x64 (Windows 7 Enterprise) desktop, WatiN fails to find open browsers.

Internally i believe, WatiN is programmed to enumerate all open windows using the Win32 API, and see if any match the given criteria.

My question is: If my process is loaded as a x86 (I see *32 next to in in taskmgr), calling some method that is marked with **DllImport( ... )** May potentially load the x64 version? (EnumWindows is defined in User32.dll for example), which version of it is loaded then? The one in *C:\Windows\System32* or the one in *C:\Windows\SysWOW64*

Our application is compiled in x86 configuration, however some of the referenced assemblies are compiled in "Any CPU".

Can that cause any issues of properly loading the correct versions (x86/x64) references DLLs/assemblies?

EDIT: Added a memory dump of loaded modules: http://www.pasteall.org/27134/text

Note that some modules are actually loaded from Windows\SysWOW64 and others like SHDocVW.dll are from C:\Windows\System32

Can this point out to a possible collision between 32/64 on that system?

I have debugged WatiN's code up to the point where a call to some native method to enumerate windows returns null (although some IE windows were available).

How can i further debug this strange issue?

As part of diagnostic testing on the failing machine (this doesn't occur on all machines), i have made a simple diagnostic application that references a lib that calls EnumWindows.

Something like this:

DebugApp -> DebugLib

Each of these was compiled in x86 and Any CPU, and the 4 different combinations were tested.

1. I ran this on my desktop (32 bit) which caused in 4 identical
   outputs.
2. On a Windows Server 2008 R2 (64 bit) it created 3 identical outputs,
   and 1 run crashed (As Expected - 64Bit EXE with a 32bit Lib).
3. On the machine that is failing, this created 4 identical files, like
   mine, how this can be? it should've resulted in an app crash!!

Any ideas after this diagnostic?

Comment: It should load the same one that the programming is running in so if your program is running in 32 bit then it loads the 32 bit one etc... You can try and force 32 bit in your visual studio project to see if that helps.

Comment: What happens if the application (exe) is a x86 process, but some referenced  assemblies are compiled in Any CPU configuration? can that cause issues when running code that performs some COM interop ?

Comment: AFAIK not really, the only issues I've had in 64 bit COM is sending structures that have to be a specific size (since in 64 bit the size of IntPtr is different). Also watin should be able to get handles to windows by searching for the process or name regardless of it being 32/64 bit so if it's not finding it something my not be setup correctly (I had that issue before).

Comment: Can you specify which method it uses? There are differences when enumerating IE8 windows and IE9 windows because of class names and such. Also when you force 32 bit does it work?

Comment: My next step would be to try the x86 compiled version. The method used is WatiNs implementation detail but IIRC it is EnumWindows defined in user32

Comment: That sounds about right. It's probably returning false at that point because the window wasn't found, not really sure what exactly it's using to compare against (window title, class name, etc...) so my guess is that that's the problem.

Comment: It is looking for ALL top level windows currently available and returns null. The same application & code identifies the same window on another desktop.

Comment: Did run the test runner with administrative privileges? I had similar issues, until I didn't run NUnit as Administrator.

Comment: yes we also tried that, although we are running WatiN from within an application and not NUnit.

Comment: there is a flaw in WatiN PInvoke calls for 64b system. Check my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/a/24928667/3523656